# LibGdx project execution fails in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, libgdx, game-development

since I am new to LibGDX and have recently setUp the libgdx and IntelliJ platform, I am having trouble while I run the project.

It displays the following message in console :

> **Execution failed for task ':desktop:DesktopLauncher.main()'.
>
> > Process 'command 'C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-17.0.1/bin/java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
>
> - Try:
>
> > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> > Run with --scan to get full insights.**

please help me how do I configure my project properly.

Comment: This error message barely contains any information. Like the error message suggests: run the gradle task with a `--stacktrace` option to see the root cause of this error. To do this you need to open a console in your desktop project and run `gradle run --stacktrace`